# ANTLR for Writing JAPE Grammar

Tags: nlp, antlr, text-processing, gate

I am using GATE to process texts written in natural language. I have to extract height, weight, bp etc from the text and store it in structured form. Now, these things(i.e height, weight etc) can be written in many forms which is unknown to me. Writing JAPE grammar for all the different ways I can come up with, is merely hard-coding it. Do I have any other option to process the docs in a more flexible way?

Also, I am confused as to whether I can use ANTLR to generate jape grammar by presenting different ways of writing height, weight etc?

The text will contain the following:

```
Vitals: Height: 72 inches, Weight is 170 pounds, T is 89.9 degree Fahrenheit. OR
Vitals: He is 184 cm tall, his weight was 67.8 Kg, RR 16 (its respiration rate). OR
Vitals: height is 6ft 3 in, he weighs 70 kg, pulse is 67, Temperature 99.8 degrees.
```

Now I use JAPE grammar and ANNIE to tokenize the text to extract these vitals and store in structured form. Will using ANTLR be flexible to tokenize this such text? Flexible in the sense that I should not hard-code it for each way of representation, as you see height, weight etc can be represented in many forms.

Will that be a good idea to search for or develop any grammar generator that would generate jape grammars?

If you require any detail to better understand the problem pls let me know.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: _"whether I can use ANTLR to generate jape grammar"_, I am not familiar with jape or GATE, but ANTLR is in general ill suited for NLP. Nor does ANTLR generate other grammars: ANTLR takes a BNF-like grammar which it converts to a lexer and/or parser that can tokenize and/or parse the language you defined in said BNF-like grammar. If you still think ANTLR could be used in your case, please edit your question and provide some concrete examples of your input, and the corresponding (desired) output.

Comment: @Bart: Thx for the edit and your suggestion! Is my problem now clear?

Comment: No, I would not use ANTLR for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try JAPE lightway alternative [Gexp](http://code.google.com/p/graph-expression/)

Comment: what is JAPE lightway? On searching I do not get any result related to GATE's JAPE grammar.

Comment: Oh sorry, you mean GExp as being a lightway alternative to JAPE?

Comment: Yes Gexp is lightway version of GATE as for me. As for GATE it is easy to find tutorial with google (http://gate.ac.uk/sale/thakker-jape-tutorial/GATE%20JAPE%20manual.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had been through the tutorial before. Using JAPE is not a problem but was thinking if there could be a better solution to it. Thanks neways!! :)